# Massive memory comsumption on .net core 2.2 project. how do i lower memory usage?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

UPDATE: It seems like, IIS is restarting due to the max memory of the app-pool being used(1024mb).

With some search, its a bug in .net 2.0-2.2 but should be improved a lot in 3.0.

I tried setting Server garbage collection to false in CSProj file, and it have improved the logged in time a lot.

Is there any other way that i can improve memory loss?

---

I have a website with a login system based on the standard identity used by .net core 2.2. Startet to work fine, but lately it began to disconnect users after 1 minute, whether they are idle or doing something active. The user then have to enter credentials again to get back in.

I tried adding Cookie expiration, setting the expire to all kinds of values. I even tried setting the sliding expiration to true. It makes no difference. Maybe its becaurse of my lacking of understanding how authentication works. 
Here is my startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<WebsiteJobs>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        //REF:https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/08/asp-net-core-2-0-cookie-authentication/
        //Cookie Authentication Options

        //Login View
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        //Logout Action
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        //Controls how much time the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created. 
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        //Ticket Expiration :represents the expiration of the ticket NOT the cookie that contains the ticket.
        //an expired cookie will be ignored even if it is passed to the server after the browser should have purged it.
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        //Cookie Expiration
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        //override default name of cookie, which is .AspNetCore.Cookies
        options.Cookie.Name = "expirationLoginCookie";
        //cookie can be accessed from client side scripts
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;


        //ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl"
    });
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
        //services.AddTransient<UserAccess>();
        services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddElmahIo(o =>
        {
            o.ApiKey = "0966aa5059844c5e9d7263e47b41bdd0";
            o.LogId = new Guid("ddb3359e-6fc4-4bdc-801b-7e8d4d68a76c");
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorLoggingMiddleware>();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseElmahIo();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/WebMaster/WebsiteJobs", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
        });


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
               template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: recheck your deployment, something might be causing the application to restart, hence losing the session information

Comment: @SahaKPGhoshal Im not sure how to do this. Is there anywhere that i can log that, or find information on the deployment? What can cause an application restart?

Comment: @SahaKPGhoshal - Your comment took me in the right direction :-D It turned out to be a server restart problem :-D You can post an answer if you like ;-)

Comment: Great to hear that you have resolved the issue.